# I messed up trying to set python3 as default on Linux mint

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint, python3

Okay, so I did a quick Google search on how to set python3 as default. I came across this code:

```
echo "alias python='python3'" >> .bashrc
source .bashrc
```

Typed it into the terminal and it didn't work as I wanted so I double-checked I didn't make any mistakes and I wasn't (and am still not) sure what the `>>` means. I think once or twice I just did,

```
.bashrc source .bashrc
```

When I start a terminal now it says:

```
-bash: alias: source: not found 
-bash alias: .bashrc: not found
-bash: alias: source: not found 
-bash alias: .bashrc: not found
my@my-hp:~$
```

I've got it all messed up. I have no idea how to fix this and erase what I've done.

The good news is when I type "python" into the terminal it runs python3, but I still can't run a py file by typing it in the terminal after changing the directory to the appropriate folders as I wanted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The `>>` means to append the previous command's output to the following file.

Except what you should have run is

```
echo "alias python='python3'" >> .bashrc ; source .bashrc
```

Because you left out the `;` the source command instead of being run was added to your `.bashrc`.   You should edit it and remove all of those source commands.

Adding the alias command to your bashrc makes it permanent in your account, but only takes effect next time you open a shell.  Running source on your .bashrc re-executes the contents of that file, which would cause the alias in the file to be added to your current shell.  I would recommend just using cut and paste to run the alias command directly when you first create it instead of sourcing the bashrc.  (But either way works.)

If you want to run .py files directly, you have to add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as the first line of the .py file and then make it executable with `chmod +x`.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  How do I edit and remove the source commands? Sorry I'm such a noob.

Comment: Don't rely on Google to configure Linux - or - "a little knowledge can be dangerous".
Obviously, you need to edit `.bashrc` in the home directory of the user where you damaged your `bash` configuration file.

Comment: Good noob editors would include gedit and nano.  Real uinx users would use vi or emacs.  :-P

Comment: I have never really got to grips with vi or emacs - so I use nano a lot. BTW Why not create a symbolic link for python3?

Comment: If you mean creating a symbolic link in your home directory, that works.  If you mean creating it at the system level to replace the system python, this will break anything on the system that expects the `python` command to be a specific version of python.  This could seriously break your system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will back you out of your error, but once you recover from that, you should consider using the `update-alternatives` utility - it's made for situations in which more than one version of the same program is installed. Here's a walk-through to change the default Python from 2.X to 3.Y

Verify your system's *baseline* (this is from **my** system):

```bsh
$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

To make the `python` command default to use `python3`:

```bsh
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
```

The response should be:

> update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode

Check baseline again:

```bsh
$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

See `man update-alternatives` for details. If you want to "undo" this:

```bsh
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 10
```

Which should yield this response:

> update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python2.7 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode